# Can XPathSelectElement ignore case?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5, xpath

Is there a way to ignore case when we try to use **XPathSelectElement** or any operation like to retrieving attributes from XDocument? The purpose for asking this question is that, I have some configuration files (xml) and I am writing a generic code that will read the config files to get required information for XPathSelectElement. Also, I try to get the values of attributes. Even if someone puts the nodes/attributes in different case, my program should be able to work without fail.

I use C#/.Net 3.5.

Comment: Consider to write an XML schema for your documents that defines the proper case of any element and attribute names. Then validate any incoming documents against the schema and reject invalid documents. That is how XML is supposed to work. Ignoring the case of names in the case-sensitive world of XML is not something you should aim for.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your response. Can you please point me to some link which shows this approach in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can't ignore case with XPath. You can accomodate, though.

For example - elements, assuming they contain letters in the ASCII range only:

```
//*[
  translate(
    name(), 
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  ) = 'myname'
]
```

Attributes would work the same (with `@*` in place of `*`).

If you do not want to bloat your XPath expressions with this, you could lower-case all element- and attribute names beforehand, for example via XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
  <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />

  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(name(), $upper, $lower)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{translate(name(), $upper, $lower)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code to show how to use them in the code?

Comment: No. This is pretty basic stuff and you should be able to figure this out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Before you load the XML string make lower-case. That will solve the issue. I use this method myself.